# displaying data on webpage2 sent through querystring from webpage1

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, query-string

So i am enteringsome text in textarea and sending the data through query string to different webpage. Basically I want to display data on the other webpage. This is my code but it is not working though I checked on console, data is getting to webpage2 but it is not displaying on html page. What i am doing wrong?

//code to redirect to webpage 2 and sending data in querystring after encoding

```js
   location.href= "https://one.dummyjs.open.html?concern=" + encodeURIComponent($("#concern").val());
```

//Code to display data on webpage2

```js
   var queryString = new Array();
    $(function () {
        if (queryString.length == 0) {
            if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
                var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                    var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                    queryString[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        if (queryString["concern"] != null ) {
    
            var data = queryString["concern"] ;
            $("textarea#u_issue_description").val(data);
        
        }
    });
    
    $(p).html(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "main-container">
        <p></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second Page you need only this

**Jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var queryString = new Array();
        $(function () {
            if (queryString.length == 0) {
                if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
                    var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
                    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                        var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                        var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                        queryString[key] = value;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (queryString["concern"] != null) {

                var data = queryString["concern"];
                //$("textarea#u_issue_description").val(data);
                $('#pTest').text(data);

            }
        });            
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class= "main-container">
        <p id="pTest"></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: what changes did u make?

Comment: There are 2 changes
1. Code is place inside document.ready.
2. In the shared code there is no control text area on page 2. I commented that code.